# sudo apt-add-repository | gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: linux, terminal, apt

Help please, i am trying to install Cubic, but i have an error:
When i run
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release`
I see this output:

```
      ///////
     ///\   \
    ///  \___\  Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator
    \ \  /////
     \ \/////
      \_____\

 Cubic (Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator) is a GUI wizard to create a customized Ubuntu Live ISO image.

 More info: https://launchpad.net/cubic
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~cubic-wizard/+archive/ubuntu/release
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpo8ioi6s7/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpo8ioi6s7/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 081525E2B4F1283B: public key "Launchpad PPA for PJ Singh" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I am using Kali Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands used to install cubic:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys B66730E51B4FB887805AE5ACDCBB7672F59F99D6 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cubic
```